# How to move to the next object using the array of count in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I am working with infinite scrolling using uicollectionview.But  I am trying when user click on the “Next”(Button) the should change to the next object. Like

I have an array like   `" arrayOfItems = ["Apple","Ball","Cat","Rat”]”`

If in collection view Cell I am displaying “Apple” in a label.

If I click on the next button “Ball” is coming.

If I click again on next button,It is not scrolling to next object.

My code is like this :

```
   func reversePhotoArray(arrayItems:[String], startIndex:Int, endIndex:Int){
        if startIndex >= endIndex{
            return
        }
        swap(&arrayOfItems[startIndex], &arrayOfItems[endIndex])

        reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: startIndex + 1, endIndex: endIndex - 1)
    }

}
  @IBAction func nextButtonMethod(sender: AnyObject) {


      //   let fullyScrolledContentOffset:CGFloat = infiniteScrollingCollectionView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(photosUrlArray.count - 1)


        //  reversePhotoArray(photosUrlArray, startIndex:  0 + 1, endIndex: photosUrlArray.count - 1)


            reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: photosUrlArray.count - 1)
            reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: 1)

            reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 2, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)
        reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)
        reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 3)
        reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 2, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)
            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
            infiniteScrollingCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)



//            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: photosUrlArray.count - 2, inSection: 0)
//            infiniteScrollingCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)



    }


extension InfiniteScrollingViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arrayOfItems.count

    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InfiniteScrollingCell

        let photoName = photoForIndexPath(indexPath)

        cell.label.text = photoName

     cell.configureCell(photoName)



        return cell

    }

}
```

Can Anyone help me to solve this issue.What mistake I am doing here.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your next button is always scrolling to row 1.
Try this :

```
var nextRow = 1

@IBAction func nextButtonMethod(sender: AnyObject) {

  //   let fullyScrolledContentOffset:CGFloat = infiniteScrollingCollectionView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(photosUrlArray.count - 1)

     //  reversePhotoArray(photosUrlArray, startIndex:  0 + 1, endIndex: photosUrlArray.count - 1)


    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: photosUrlArray.count - 1)
    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: 1)

    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 2, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)
    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)
    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: 0, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 3)
    reversePhotoArray(arrayOfItems, startIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 2, endIndex: arrayOfItems.count - 1)

    if nextRow < arrayOfItems.count {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: nextRow, inSection: 0)
        infiniteScrollingCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)
        nextRow += 1
    }

//            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: photosUrlArray.count - 2, inSection: 0)
//            infiniteScrollingCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Left, animated: false)



}
```

Comment: It is crashing If I click after "Rat" data ERROR:"attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"

Comment: @anushahrithi what do you want it to do after "Rat"? go back to the first one or do nothing?